# Rails Feedzirra: Parse links from Feed entry titles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, rss, feedzirra

I have examined the object data of a Feedzirra::Feed.fetch_and_parse() object coming from a feed. The feed I'm using is http://feeds.feedburner.com/ChrisBurnor

My issue is that if a title on this page is linked to an external site Feedzirra does not pick up on it, in this case, the entry titled "Space Colony Art from the 1970's" links to publicdomainreview.com. Yet the link itself is not present anywhere in the Feedzirra returned object.

My question: Is there a known RSS element that contains the href material from an entry title?
Or: Is there a way I can examine the xml of this feed to see if I can perhaps find where the link is going...

For the future, I might want to peer inside of these links and include their material in my feed display but for now I just want to have the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the feedburner page there is a link titled "View Feed XML". When opening it and then doing a "View Page Source" in your browser, you'll see the raw XML feed. But just using wget or curl seems to be less cumbersome to me.

If you look at the raw feed, you'll see that in there is no information or link about publicdomainreview.com.

So without further processing of the feed items, you can't easily get the information you want.